# The right way to think in this problem of limits for two variables functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm solving this for help a freshman student in physics but I'm thinking that I don't know the right way to think about this.

The problem is solve that limit (if this exists):

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{xy}{y-x^3}
$$

My first attempt was check if $\frac{x}{y-x^3}$ or $\frac{y}{y-x^3}$ is limited. But those functions are not limited. So, my second attempt was make that change: $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and view what happens when $r\rightarrow 0$

$$
\frac{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{(r)[\sin\theta-r^2\cos\theta]}=\frac{r\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\sin\theta-r^2\cos\theta}\rightarrow 0 \textrm{ when } r\rightarrow 0
$$

So the limit is $0$! But that looks like wrong and this is confusing me. If I calcule this limit in the "Wolfram Alpha" the results is $0$, but if I calcule that over the curve $(^{3}\sqrt{t-t^2},t)$ that show us the limit doesn't exist (because over that curve the function goes to infinity).

The question is: **What I made wrong? Why?**

Comment: This limit does not exist.  In fact, one cannot deduce that the limit is zero by changing to polar coordinates since the limit is not unique along all paths $(r(t),\theta(t))$. You showed that when $x=(t-t^2)^{1/3}$ and $y=t$, the limit is infinity, while along the path $x=y$, the limit is zero.

Comment: But why the arguments using polar coordinates is wrong? Why that arguments don't show that the limit is $0$?

Comment: But write the function in polar coordinates is the same thing that write that in cartesian coordinates, right? That is my point.

Comment: For a multivariable limit, the limit must exist (and be the same) no matter which curve we approach from.

Comment: @mathreadler this is clear for me. I don't understand why you cannot use the polar coordinates to deduce that the limits exists and is zero.

Comment: @Felipe The limit in the OP that is converted to polar coordinates does not approach zero along all paths $(r(t),\theta(t))$.  You tacitly assumed that $\theta$ and $r$ were independent, perhaps viewing $\theta$ as constant.  $\theta $ need not be a constant; it can vary as a function of $r$ for example.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you very much! That last comment clarifIied all my wrong thoughts. =D

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.